# Interfacing Armadillo with FFTW

Tags: c++, fftw, armadillo

I am trying to use FFTW in the matrix of Armadillo package. I need to perform N independent FFT on a 2D matrix. Following the manual of FFTW and other resource online, I have the following code:

```
#include <armadillo>
#include <iostream>
#include "fftw3.h"

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

fftw_plan fplan;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  cx_mat psi;
  int NCOL=2, NROW=4;
  int frank=1;
  int howmany=NCOL;
  int n[]={NROW};         
  int idist=NROW, odist=NROW; 
  int istride=1, ostride=1;
  int *inembed=n, *onembed=n;

  psi.resize(NROW, NCOL);
  psi(0,0)=cx_double(1,1); psi(0,1)=cx_double(1,1);
  psi(1,0)=cx_double(2,1); psi(1,1)=cx_double(1,2);
  psi(2,0)=cx_double(3,1); psi(2,1)=cx_double(1,3);
  psi(3,0)=cx_double(4,1); psi(3,1)=cx_double(1,4);
  cout << psi << endl; // the output is correct at here

  fftw_complex* in = reinterpret_cast<fftw_complex*>(psi.memptr());

  fplan = fftw_plan_many_dft(frank, n, howmany,
                             in, inembed, istride, idist,
                             in, onembed, ostride, odist,
                             FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_MEASURE);

  cout << endl << "after fftw plan: " << endl << psi << endl; // all zeros

  // fftw_execute(fplan); // output zeros again if execute
  cx_double* A_mem=psi.memptr();
  cout << endl << "by reference: " << endl << *A_mem << " " << *(A_mem+1) << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

The code compiles without any error. But if I run the code, after fftw_plan_many_dft, it outputs all zeroes instead. If I remove fftw_plan_many_dft, the output is correct. I don't even execute the fftw plan so why it clean my data by just setting up the plan?

Comment: With the `FFTW_MEASURE` flag the buffers are actually used to tune the FFT algorithm. You should create the plan *first*, and then initialise the input data.

Comment: oh. That solves the problem. Thanks.

Comment: No problem - comment converted to answer now, for the benefit of any future readers with a similar problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `FFTW_MEASURE` flag the buffers are actually used to tune the FFT algorithm. You should create the plan first, and then initialise the input data.

Note that `FFTW_ESTIMATE` does *not* exhibit this behaviour, so you could also just change this flag in your current code to fix the problem, but then your code would probably run slower.